# Launching batch file from JAVA not working for directory path having spaces

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, copy, xcopy

I have created a batch file with the following contents

```
xcopy "C:\Documents\javascript\src\*" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\docs\8.1\version1\" /s /y
```

I am running the batch file using Java. Running the script from command line or directly executing it(double clicking) doesn't seem to have any problem. However when I run using java the copy operation doesn't succeed. In the console I see a message *More?* when the script is executed.

Also running the copy operation for directory path without spaces seems to work fine.
Here is the java method which does the batch file running.

```
   public void run(String input)
  {     
    File dir = new File(input);
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
    processBuilder.redirectInput(dir);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    int exitStatus = process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();
  }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could help the readers if you post your code for launching this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the way you are launching the bat file
for me this works fine:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start xcopy-file.bat"`

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was using ProcessBuilder class to run my .bat files